# Read newer files first from a directory - C++

Tags: c++

Lets say I have a directory which has the files with the following names:

00
01
02
03
04
05
...

The higher the number, the newer the file. I want to read say the 2 newest files but in descending order. So I want to read the 05 file first, then 04 file.

How can I achieve this efficiently? This directory can have 100's of files.

I know there is a readdir function in C++ but it reads the files in ascending order (First 00, then 01 and so on).

Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Filesystem is not an SQL server, it does not give out file lists sorted etc.. You have to iterate through all files and look at their timestamps. Then process them in whatever order you like. 100s of files is no big deal. Your bottleneck will be in file I/O anyway.

Comment: "a readdir function … reads the files in ascending order" - No, it doesn't. It reads the files in directory order. You should not rely upon the order that `readdir` returns.

Answer (score 3):

Create an array of the filenames, sort the array in descending order, read the files in order of the newly sorted array.

Comment: But the names are unlikely to correspond to chronological order.

Comment: @MarkR - OP said they do. “The higher the number, the newer the file.”

Comment: fair enough, I seem to have missed that part

Answer (score 1):

You could use `boost::filesystem` and `std::sort` to sort and then iterate through the files

```
struct comparator {
    bool operator()(boost::filesystem::path i, 
                    boost::filesystem::path j)
    { 
        return (i>j);
    }

} myComparator;

...

boost::filesystem::path folderPath = "/path/to/some/folder";

if (boost::filesystem::exists(folderPath))
{
    if (boost::filesystem::is_directory(folderPath))
    {
        typedef std::vector<boost::filesystem::path> vec;
        vec v;

        std::copy(
            boost::filesystem::directory_iterator(folderPath),
            boost::filesystem::directory_iterator(),
            std::back_inserter(v)
        );

        std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), myComparator);

        for (vec::const_iterator it(v.begin()); it != v.end; ++it)
        {
            std::cout << "File: " << *it << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did not check the code but this should give you an idea how it should look like. Read the file list, sort it and open the files in the correct order.

```
DIR dir;
struct dirent *dir_entry;
dir = opendir("dir/path")

std::vector<std::string> file_list;
file_list.reserve(N);
while(dir=readdir(dir))
{
  if (dir_entry->d_type == DT_REG)
  {
    file_list.push_back(std::string(dir_entry->d_name));
  }
}
std::sort(file_list.begin(), file_list.end());
// open files ...
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `popen("ls -t", "r")`

Comment: Seriously? Why not write the whole thing in Bash then?